# I can't place an image in table without breaking other cells' alignments

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put an image in my table but when I place the `img` tag in between `<td>` tags; content of neighbor cell acts like there is `<br>` tags on top of it.

I tried to use `display:inline-block` but didn't effect anything.

question: how can I make "neighboor content" stay up?

```html
<table height="100%" width="100%" border="solid black 1px">
  <tr class="Content">
    <td class="left">
      <img src="sample.jpg" width="250px" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <table class="right">
        <tr>
          <td class="Title">
            <h2> Title of movie </h2> 
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="description">
          <td>Description of movie</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="Actors">
          <td>
            <h2> Actors of movie </h2>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="buttons">
          <td colspan="2">
            <p>Option buttons will be here.</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here is relative CSS styles.

```css
.content {
  background-color: white;
}
.content .left {
  vertical-align: text-top;
  width: 250px;
}
.content .right {
  vertical-align: text-top;
}
```

Comment: Did you use any type of styles in this page,??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope, you wanted to make the right column content aligned to top (sorry, but it is not exactly clear to me...)
So, try this:

```html
<table height="100%" width="100%" border="solid black 1px">
  <tr class="Content">
    <td class="left">
      <img src="sample.jpg" width="250px" />
    </td>
    <td style="vertical-align: top"> <!-- Here is the "trick" -->
      <table class="right">
        <tr>
          <td class="Title">
            <h2> Title of movie </h2> 
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="description">
          <td>Description of movie</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="Actors">
          <td>
            <h2> Actors of movie </h2>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="buttons">
          <td colspan="2">
            <p>Option buttons will be here.</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes. That was exactly what I was asking for. And this works! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Please add an ID to table like

```
<Table id="tblnotify">
```

use this css code

```
#tblnotify td{
   vertical-align: top;    //align td to top
   padding:2px;       //it is not good view to stick on top of the table.leave a little space for a better look.
}
```

regds